# Selected tabs not stay in Tab layout in Adndroid

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

when i click on navigation drawer item the first tab is selected fine.
after selected second item from drawer then second tab is just selected for few seconds and it will move on first tab. same as others

[the first tab is selected from navigation drawer, it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWelO.png)

[now as per selected second menu from drawer it automatically move first tab after few seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRhZe.jpg)

```
This code block run for view pager 

  if (Share.getSetCheckVariable().equals("Products")) {
            boolean b = true;
            Share.setSetCheckVariable("Products");
            for (int i = 0; i < productSize; i++) {
                fragment = new ImageListFragmentImageListFragment();
                bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("type", i);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                if (b) {
                    for (int g = 0; g < subCategories_Size; g++) {
                        b = false;
                        adapter.addFragment(fragment, sub_categories.get(g));
                    }
                }
            }
        }


This code block run when click on navigation drawer item    

    for (int i = 0; i < subCategories_Size; i++) {
                    if (id == i) {
                        Share.setSetCheckVariable("Products");
                        get_productDetails(sub_categoriesID.get(i));
                        b = true;
                        myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                productSize = Share.getProduct_name().size();
                                setupViewPager(viewPager);
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(id);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not changed the value of `id` or the value of `i`, hence when you run :

```
for (int i = 0; i < subCategories_Size; i++) {
                    if (id == i) {
                        Share.setSetCheckVariable("Products");
                        get_productDetails(sub_categoriesID.get(i));
                        b = true;
                        myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                productSize = Share.getProduct_name().size();
                                setupViewPager(viewPager);
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(id);
            }
```

It displays the first one because `viewPager.setCurrentItem(id);` has `id` = 1.

Moreover you should use `onClickListener` instead

Comment: why it goes for few seconds after click on drawer iten

Comment: one more thing i have checked when i click the drawer item the id is changed

Comment: @TaimurTanveer  why are you using delay?

Comment: Add delay with Oncclicklistener

Comment: kindly share another solution

Comment: Hey sorry, but can you wait. I am running it right now. I think you have a problem with the Adapter.java